# Return TreeView from WCF Service in SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services, wcf

How to return TreeView from WCF Service ? Its giving error when we set return type as TreeView

Comment: Can you please add more details, like your current code and the error message you get to this post?

Answer (score 1):

List of valid WCF return types

- Primitive types (string, int32, etc...)
- Complex types with DataContract or Serializable attributes
- Stream
- Message
- SyndicationFeedFormatter
- Void

There is no return type like TreeView. maximum you can get the xml out of WCF service and bind it to TreeView control.